# How can add the same wildcard hostname to multiple Azure web apps?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I want to add a wildcard hostname to multiple Azure WebApps e.g. *.mydomain.com

I have read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-custom-domain-name-migrate which suggests I can bind the domain name pre-emptively using a TXT DNS record.

> To verify domain ownership, Add a TXT record. The TXT record maps from awverify. to .azurewebsites.net.

I have tried to add `awverify.* TXT myapp.azurewebsites.net` but get error message:

> Each label must only contain letters, numbers, underscores, and/or dashes. Each label should be separated from other labels by a period. A wildcard ('*' character) is permitted either as the single character in the name, or as the first label in the name.

I want to assign the wildcard domain to multiple WebApps and they change the DNS CNames for specific subdomains without an downtime.

How is this possible?

Comment: This might [help](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/06/21/custom-hostnames-with-app-service/) you. Let me know if this helps

Comment: This does not work: `Our custom hostname feature allows you to bypass validation for hostnames that have already been validated. You only need to verify domain ownership when you add a hostname for the first time. For all other apps in the same subscription, you can add the same hostname without creating any DNS records.` It always asks to validate the hostname in a new site within the same subscription.

Answer (score 0):

> How can add the same wildcard hostname to multiple Azure web apps?

In short **no way**.

When you add the wildcard hostname to another app service, it seems that there is already a record set with the same name this DNS zone. **You can only  have one HOST that equals to ***.

Maybe you could `Add hostname` with *.domain.com in different azure service plan, but you could not visit it.
[image]
BTW,You can use either a `CNAME record` or an `A record` to map a custom DNS name to App Service.

A TXT record to map to the app's default hostname .azurewebsites.net. App Service uses this record **only at configuration time**, to **verify** that you own the custom domain. After your custom domain is validated and configured in App Service, you can **delete this TXT record**.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2015/12/01/mapping-a-wildcard-domain-name-to-an-azure-app-services-web-app-website/).

Answer (score 0):

You **can** add the same custom hostname to multiple Azure Web Apps, even wildcards, if they are not in the same subscription AND in the same region. This is not well documented; I spent an afternoon with Azure support to learn of this restriction.

Your TXT record is almost correct. It should be `awverify TXT myapp.azurewebsites.net` for a wildcard hostname, assuming your Azure Web App's name is "myapp".